# При попытке отправить структуру из C# в функции на C в DLL возникает MarshalDirectiveException

Tags: c#, c, dll, marshal

Есть структура данных на `C#`

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 0)]
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public struct rtksvr_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {
            /* RTK server type */
            public int state;          /* server state (0:stop,1:running) */
            public int cycle;          /* processing cycle (ms) */
            public int nmeacycle;      /* NMEA request cycle (ms) (0:no req) */
            public int nmeareq;        /* NMEA request (0:no,1:nmeapos,2:single sol) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public double[] nmeapos;  /* NMEA request position (ecef) (m) */
            public int buffsize;       /* input buffer size (bytes) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public int[] format;      /* input format {rov,base,corr} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 2)]
            public solopt_t[] solopt; /* output solution options {sol1,sol2} */
            public int navsel;         /* ephemeris select (0:all,1:rover,2:base,3:corr) */
            public int nsbs;           /* number of sbas message */
            public int nsol;           /* number of solution buffer */
            public rtk_t rtk;          /* RTK control/result struct */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public int[] nb;         /* bytes in input buffers {rov,base} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
            public int[] nsb;         /* bytes in soulution buffers */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public int[] npb;         /* bytes in input peek buffers */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public byte[] buff; /* input buffers {rov,base,corr} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
            public byte[] sbuf; /* output buffers {sol1,sol2} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public byte[] pbuf; /* peek buffers {rov,base,corr} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSOLBUF)]
            public sol_t[] solbuf; /* solution buffer */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3 * 10)]
            public int[] nmsg; /* input message counts */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 3)]
            public raw_t[] raw;     /* receiver raw control {rov,base,corr} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 3)]
            public rtcm_t[] rtcm;     /* RTCM control {rov,base,corr} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 3)]
            public gtime_t[] ftime;   /* download time {rov,base,corr} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3 * MAXSTRPATH)]
            public char[] files; /* download paths {rov,base,corr} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 3 * MAXOBSBUF)]
            public obs_t[] obs; /* observation data {rov,base,corr} */
            public nav_t nav;          /* navigation data */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = MAXSBSMSG)]
            public sbsmsg_t[] sbsmsg; /* SBAS message buffer */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 8)]
            public stream_t[] stream; /* streams {rov,base,corr,sol1,sol2,logr,logb,logc} */
            public IntPtr moni;     /* monitor stream */
            public uint tick;  /* start tick */
            public IntPtr thread;    /* server thread */
            public int cputime;        /* CPU time (ms) for a processing cycle */
            public int prcout;         /* missing observation data count */
            public int nave;           /* number of averaging base pos */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public double[] rb_ave;   /* averaging base pos */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3 * MAXRCVCMD)]
            public char[] cmds_periodic; /* periodic commands */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXRCVCMD)]
            public char[] cmd_reset; /* reset command */
            public double bl_reset;    /* baseline length to reset (km) */
            public CRITICAL_SECTION lock_flag;        /* lock flag */
        };
```

Оригинал на `C`

```
typedef struct {        /* RTK server type */
    int state;          /* server state (0:stop,1:running) */
    int cycle;          /* processing cycle (ms) */
    int nmeacycle;      /* NMEA request cycle (ms) (0:no req) */
    int nmeareq;        /* NMEA request (0:no,1:nmeapos,2:single sol) */
    double nmeapos[3];  /* NMEA request position (ecef) (m) */
    int buffsize;       /* input buffer size (bytes) */
    int format[3];      /* input format {rov,base,corr} */
    solopt_t solopt[2]; /* output solution options {sol1,sol2} */
    int navsel;         /* ephemeris select (0:all,1:rover,2:base,3:corr) */
    int nsbs;           /* number of sbas message */
    int nsol;           /* number of solution buffer */
    rtk_t rtk;          /* RTK control/result struct */
    int nb [3];         /* bytes in input buffers {rov,base} */
    int nsb[2];         /* bytes in soulution buffers */
    int npb[3];         /* bytes in input peek buffers */
    unsigned char *buff[3]; /* input buffers {rov,base,corr} */
    unsigned char *sbuf[2]; /* output buffers {sol1,sol2} */
    unsigned char *pbuf[3]; /* peek buffers {rov,base,corr} */
    sol_t solbuf[MAXSOLBUF]; /* solution buffer */
    unsigned int nmsg[3][10]; /* input message counts */
    raw_t  raw [3];     /* receiver raw control {rov,base,corr} */
    rtcm_t rtcm[3];     /* RTCM control {rov,base,corr} */
    gtime_t ftime[3];   /* download time {rov,base,corr} */
    char files[3][MAXSTRPATH]; /* download paths {rov,base,corr} */
    obs_t obs[3][MAXOBSBUF]; /* observation data {rov,base,corr} */
    nav_t nav;          /* navigation data */
    sbsmsg_t sbsmsg[MAXSBSMSG]; /* SBAS message buffer */
    stream_t stream[8]; /* streams {rov,base,corr,sol1,sol2,logr,logb,logc} */
    stream_t *moni;     /* monitor stream */
    unsigned int tick;  /* start tick */
    thread_t thread;    /* server thread */
    int cputime;        /* CPU time (ms) for a processing cycle */
    int prcout;         /* missing observation data count */
    int nave;           /* number of averaging base pos */
    double rb_ave[3];   /* averaging base pos */
    char cmds_periodic[3][MAXRCVCMD]; /* periodic commands */
    char cmd_reset[MAXRCVCMD]; /* reset command */
    double bl_reset;    /* baseline length to reset (km) */
    lock_t lock;        /* lock flag */
} rtksvr_t;
```

Функция на `C`

```
extern __declspec(dllexport)  int __stdcall rtksvrinit(rtksvr_t *svr)
{
    gtime_t time0={0};
    sol_t  sol0 ={{0}};
    eph_t  eph0 ={0,-1,-1};
    geph_t geph0={0,-1};
    seph_t seph0={0};
    int i,j;

    tracet(3,"rtksvrinit:\n");

    svr->state=svr->cycle=svr->nmeacycle=svr->nmeareq=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->nmeapos[i]=0.0;
    svr->buffsize=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->format[i]=0;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) svr->solopt[i]=solopt_default;
    svr->navsel=svr->nsbs=svr->nsol=0;
    rtkinit(&svr->rtk,&prcopt_default);
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->nb[i]=0;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) svr->nsb[i]=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->npb[i]=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->buff[i]=NULL;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) svr->sbuf[i]=NULL;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->pbuf[i]=NULL;
    for (i=0;i<MAXSOLBUF;i++) svr->solbuf[i]=sol0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) for (j=0;j<10;j++) svr->nmsg[i][j]=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->ftime[i]=time0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->files[i][0]='\0';
    svr->moni=NULL;
    svr->tick=0;
    svr->thread=0;
    svr->cputime=svr->prcout=svr->nave=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->rb_ave[i]=0.0;

    if (!(svr->nav.eph =(eph_t  *)malloc(sizeof(eph_t )*MAXSAT *2))||
        !(svr->nav.geph=(geph_t *)malloc(sizeof(geph_t)*NSATGLO*2))||
        !(svr->nav.seph=(seph_t *)malloc(sizeof(seph_t)*NSATSBS*2))) {
        tracet(1,"rtksvrinit: malloc error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (i=0;i<MAXSAT *2;i++) svr->nav.eph [i]=eph0;
    for (i=0;i<NSATGLO*2;i++) svr->nav.geph[i]=geph0;
    for (i=0;i<NSATSBS*2;i++) svr->nav.seph[i]=seph0;
    svr->nav.n =MAXSAT *2;
    svr->nav.ng=NSATGLO*2;
    svr->nav.ns=NSATSBS*2;

    for (i=0;i<3;i++) for (j=0;j<MAXOBSBUF;j++) {
        if (!(svr->obs[i][j].data=(obsd_t *)malloc(sizeof(obsd_t)*MAXOBS))) {
            tracet(1,"rtksvrinit: malloc error\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
        memset(svr->raw +i,0,sizeof(raw_t ));
        memset(svr->rtcm+i,0,sizeof(rtcm_t));
    }
    for (i=0;i<MAXSTRRTK;i++) strinit(svr->stream+i);

    for (i=0;i<3;i++) *svr->cmds_periodic[i]='\0';
    *svr->cmd_reset='\0';
    svr->bl_reset=10.0;
    initlock(&svr->lock);

    return 1;
}
```

Импорт ее в `C#`

```
[DllImport("RTKLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "rtksvrinit")]
        public static extern int rtksvrinit(ref rtksvr_t svr);
```

Пытаюсь инициализировать структуру и вызвать функцию в `C#`

try

```
{
                iSizeRTKSRV = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DataRTK.rtksvr_t));
                rtksrv_ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(iSizeRTKSRV);
                rtksrv = (DataRTK.rtksvr_t)(Marshal.PtrToStructure(rtksrv_ptr, typeof(DataRTK.rtksvr_t)));
                //Marshal.FreeHGlobal(rtksrv_ptr);
                //rtksrv_ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            catch(ArgumentException ex)
            {
                string strerr = ex.Message;
            }
            catch(TypeLoadException ex)
            {
                string strerr = ex.Message;
            }

try
            {

                _ = DataRTK.rtksvrinit(ref rtksrv);
            }
            catch (TypeLoadException ex)
            {
                string strerr = ex.Message;
            }
            catch (MarshalDirectiveException ex)
            {
                string strerr = ex.Message;
            }
```

В строке `_ = DataRTK.rtksvrinit(ref rtksrv);` возникает `MarshalDirectiveException` с сообщением

> Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Internal limitation: structure is too
>   complex or too large.

Все, что нашел испробовал, но так и не смог победить эту ошибку. Кто-нибудь может подсказать хотя бы примерные варианты решения данной задачи?

**UPDATED 14.02.2020 11:11**

Структура занимает 2187640 байт памяти при ограничении на использовании ‭65520‬ байт памяти. Это не критично для хранения и изменения данных в самом классе, но при передачи ее в качестве параметра очень критично.

Сейчас пытаюсь найти обходной путь решения этой проблемы, так как в DLL используется указатель на структуру. Перебираю варианты. Но если кто подскажет варианты кроме тех, что предложены, или поделится своим опытом, буду рад оказанной помощи...

**UPDATED 14.02.2020 13:49**

Теперь переделал передаю в функцию не саму структуру, а лишь указатель

```
[DllImport("RTKLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "rtksvrinit")]
public static extern int rtksvrinit(IntPtr svr);

int result = DataRTK.rtksvrinit(rtksrv_ptr);
```

Теперь `AccessViolation` в самой функции `rtksvrinit`

```
extern __declspec(dllexport)  int __stdcall rtksvrinit(rtksvr_t *svr)
{
    gtime_t time0={0};
    sol_t  sol0 ={{0}};
    eph_t  eph0 ={0,-1,-1};
    geph_t geph0={0,-1};
    seph_t seph0={0};
    int i,j;

    tracet(3,"rtksvrinit:\n");

    svr->state=svr->cycle=svr->nmeacycle=svr->nmeareq=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->nmeapos[i]=0.0;
    svr->buffsize=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->format[i]=0;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) svr->solopt[i]=solopt_default;
    svr->navsel=svr->nsbs=svr->nsol=0;
    rtkinit(&svr->rtk,&prcopt_default);
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->nb[i]=0;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) svr->nsb[i]=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->npb[i]=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->buff[i]=NULL;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) svr->sbuf[i]=NULL;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->pbuf[i]=NULL;
    for (i=0;i<MAXSOLBUF;i++) svr->solbuf[i]=sol0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) for (j=0;j<10;j++) svr->nmsg[i][j]=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->ftime[i]=time0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->files[i][0]='\0';
    svr->moni=NULL;
    svr->tick=0;
    svr->thread=0;
    svr->cputime=svr->prcout=svr->nave=0;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->rb_ave[i]=0.0;

    if (!(svr->nav.eph =(eph_t  *)malloc(sizeof(eph_t )*MAXSAT *2))||
        !(svr->nav.geph=(geph_t *)malloc(sizeof(geph_t)*NSATGLO*2))||
        !(svr->nav.seph=(seph_t *)malloc(sizeof(seph_t)*NSATSBS*2))) {
        tracet(1,"rtksvrinit: malloc error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (i=0;i<MAXSAT *2;i++) svr->nav.eph [i]=eph0;
    for (i=0;i<NSATGLO*2;i++) svr->nav.geph[i]=geph0;
    for (i=0;i<NSATSBS*2;i++) svr->nav.seph[i]=seph0;
    svr->nav.n =MAXSAT *2;
    svr->nav.ng=NSATGLO*2;
    svr->nav.ns=NSATSBS*2;

    for (i=0;i<3;i++) for (j=0;j<MAXOBSBUF;j++) {
        if (!(svr->obs[i][j].data=(obsd_t *)malloc(sizeof(obsd_t)*MAXOBS))) {
            tracet(1,"rtksvrinit: malloc error\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
        memset(svr->raw +i,0,sizeof(raw_t ));
        memset(svr->rtcm+i,0,sizeof(rtcm_t));
    }
    for (i=0;i<MAXSTRRTK;i++) strinit(svr->stream+i);

    for (i=0;i<3;i++) *svr->cmds_periodic[i]='\0';
    *svr->cmd_reset='\0';
    svr->bl_reset=10.0;
    initlock(&svr->lock);

    return 1;
}
```

В строке

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->ftime[i]=time0;
```

Comment: Вы так и не исправили несоответствия типов, о которых я писал в предыдущей теме, так что код как есть не будет работать. Что касается ошибки "structure is too complex or too large", каков итоговый размер структуры?. В .NET Core ограничение около 65 КБ (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7e128196c0b477344888042c7c508f4624dc65ef/src/coreclr/src/vm/mlinfo.cpp#L2811).

Comment: Размер у меня показывает 2187640

Comment: По поводу несоответствия типов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097528/c-sharp-marshalling-unsigned-char-array-from-c-dll-in-and-out и еще https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke

Comment: Ограничение я знаю, меня больше интересует, что теперь с этим сделать можно, но byte я еще доберусь, но пока что следую рекомендации от Microsoft

Comment: Видимо, нужно получать структуру как блок неуправляемой памяти (IntPtr), а потом этот блок уже растаскивать в C# по структурам меньшего размера.

Comment: Блок неуправляемой памяти - это как?

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight, можно ли с Вами списаться лично или посредством коммуникатором, чтобы понять направление куда мне сейчас себя направить, потому что есть идеи как можно еще реализовать это, но пока не проходят все мои варианты. Может просто придумать какой-нибудь конвертер, который можно реализовать на C, передавать функцию с параметрами, можно реализовать класс на C# и копировать данные из него в структуру...

Comment: "Блок неуправляемой памяти - это как?" - как в последнем варианте в удаленном ответе от Alex F. Только вместо цельной структуры определить несколько меньших, и пользуясь арифметикой указателей с unsafe растащить блок по ним. Нет, я не заинтересован в том, чтобы помогать индивидуально.

Comment: Не совсем нравится мне Alex F. и его советы, так как в общем случае он прав, но не учитывает специфику моего проекта, поэтому немного не уместен, немного больше необходимо ему информации о проекте, которых он даже не просил, Ваши советы пока более приемлемы, но чувствую, что они уже иссякли, потому как есть множество способов решить данную проблему, но из-за сроков пишу здесь и нет времени на эксперименты

Comment: BYTE unsigned char System.Byte 8 bits

Comment: Вот теперь добрались до байтов чаров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение всех проблем уже описал выше, но оставалась последняя, над которой думал очень много, потому что не понимал ее корни.

Срабатывал `AccessViolation` в строке:

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++) svr->ftime[i]=time0;
```

Думал что-то с типом, но дальше в структуре происходило тоже самое. Начал смотреть сколько выделяется памяти на структуру `rtksvr_t`, в которой находится этот элемент (1911336), но по адресу указателя понял, что памяти он уже требует больше уже в этом месте (`gtime_Address - startAddress = 3000480`). То есть, явно не хватает памяти для этой структуры, потому что строка вычисляет память неправильно:

```
rtksrv_ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DataRTK.rtksvr_t)));
```

Заменил пока временно эту строку на:

```
rtksrv_ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DataRTK.rtksvr_t))*3);
```

По-крайней мере эту часть стало отрабатывать.

Проблема решена, идем дальше...